# IdentityServer Refresh AccessToken

Tags: identityserver4, access-token

Thank you for your time.I configured the AccessTokenLifetime in ids4 to be 65 seconds, and the expiration time in the user.Claims acquired by api when I accessed the api on the front end was assumed to be 8: 20: 00. I thought that no matter how I accessed the accesstoken before 8: 20: 00, the expiration time was always 8: 20: 00. I won't refresh the token until 65 seconds later, that is, this expired time. But in the actual process, I found that I started to refresh the token when I visited it after 5 seconds. Interestingly, when I set AccessTokenLifetime to 75 seconds, I will refresh the token after 15 seconds. I found this sentence in the official discussion:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr6L1.png)
He said that ids4 will refresh the token 60 seconds in advance. I wonder if I misunderstood it. Shouldn't the client do the work of refreshing the token? Why is it in ids4? If so, he said that this time can be set. How to set it?

This is my client configuration in ids4
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZEzK.png)
The following is the code for my client configuration.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            options.DefaultSignOutScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie("cookie", options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "__Host-bff";
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;

            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                //options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5002";
                options.ClientId = "interactive.confidential";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.Query;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.MapInboundClaims = false;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.Scope.Clear();
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("api");
                options.Scope.Add(StandardScopes.OfflineAccess);
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
            });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add codes/json data/markups as text in the questions/answers please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

It is always the role of the client application to trigger and do the refresh cycle, not IdentityServer. IdentityServer don't care about this. I think they refer to the automatic token management library ,that they provide that manages refresh tokens for you.

Out of the box, ASP.NET Does not care about refresh tokens.

Comment: My client is the client information configured in AddOpenIdConnect in Startup.cs, which means that the time of early refresh can be controlled here?I edited the question again, and the code configured by the client is in the question.

Comment: AddOpenIdConnect does not handle the automatic refresh of access tokens using refreshtokens. You need to implement this yourself,  see this page, there is a library that you can use for handling that https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/tokens/refresh/